# Storyboards adding insets in UITextView iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, uistoryboard

I am trying to add a UITextView to a view in Storyboards. However it only seems to work when i fill the whole view. When i shrink the UITextView vertically it maintains the upper and lower insets from the navbar and tabbar.

[image: Text gets pushed down]

Anyone know how to get rid of these insets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO` in your View Controller.